# Ask user to re-enter windows login password in .NET Winforms App

Tags: .net, authentication, c#-4.0, passwords

I have a .NET 4.0 Winforms app.  I'd like to require the user to re-enter his/her login password before using a sensitive feature.  This needs to work for users logged in through Active Directory and through Windows Networking.

So I need to pop up a dialog box that contains the username and password fields, and OK and Cancel buttons.

I'm looking to see if there is maybe a dialog box like this built into windows.  If not, I can design my own dialog box.

I believe I can determine the username using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name .  Looks like the way to authenticate is by creating a PrincipalContext and calling ValidateCredentials() on it.  Before creating the PrincipalContext, I need to know whether the user is authenticated through AD or Windows Networking, so I can construct PrincipalContext correctly.  Maybe there is some piece of code that wraps up all of this in a neat call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has an article which describes how you can validate Windows user rights at [support.micosoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841699).